# jQuery / CSS selector: Changing the value of a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this dropdown menu where currently "Job Board" is selected. In the class it has the extra attributor "select2-highlighted" and "Job Board" appears in the drop down menu.

I am trying to change this to another `<li>` under the `<ul>`.

I've read the jQuery docs and know that I should be using the `.attr()` function.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

`$('.select2-result:contains("Job Board")').attr('select2-highlighted')`

How do I "un highlight" one and highlight another? Or is there a better way to select a `<li>` inside a `<ul>`?

[image]

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: `select2-highlighted` is not a attribute....Its a class...

Comment: silly me! thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the `.toggleClass` api method. Documentation can be found here http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$('a.nav.nav-item').click(() => {
  // # remove from existing
  $('a.nav.nav-item.selected').toggleClass('selected')
  $(this).toggleClass('selected') // # toggle selected on current el
})
```